# add a column using double loops in R

Tags: r

```
patient=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
CD4=c(10.677078, 8.426150, 9.433981, 3.464102, 3.605551, 6.164414 , 6.324555, 8.124038, 4.582576, 5.000000)
```

Suppose I have a data with 3 individuals and 10 observations. Now I want to add another column (with 10 rows) with sum of CD4 values for each individual (e.g., first 3 rows will be the same value since they belong to the first patient).

I know there are very advance and easy ways to do that. But if I want to do it using double loops [for i=1 to 3 and j=1 to n_(i)], then what will be the R-code of using double loops? I am new in coding that is why sorry in advance for this lame question

Answer (score 0):

#### Clarification: Never run a double loop for this purpose, I am merely answering the question as it was asked.

```
df <- as.data.frame(list(patient=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                         CD4=c(10.677078, 8.426150, 9.433981, 3.464102, 3.605551, 6.164414 , 6.324555, 8.124038, 4.582576, 5.000000)
))

df$CD4_sum <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in unique(df$patient)) {
    df[grep(j,df$patient), "CD4_sum"] <- sum(df[grep(j,df$patient),"CD4"])
  }
}

head(df)

patient       CD4  CD4_sum
1       1 10.677078 28.53721
2       1  8.426150 28.53721
3       1  9.433981 28.53721
4       2  3.464102 19.55862
5       2  3.605551 19.55862
6       2  6.164414 19.55862
```

## Here is a more efficient way

```
> df %>% group_by(patient) %>% mutate(CD4_sum = sum(CD4))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   patient [3]
   patient   CD4 CD4_sum
     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1       1 10.7     28.5
 2       1  8.43    28.5
 3       1  9.43    28.5
 4       2  3.46    19.6
 5       2  3.61    19.6
 6       2  6.16    19.6
 7       2  6.32    19.6
 8       3  8.12    17.7
 9       3  4.58    17.7
10       3  5       17.7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I thought the loop for "i" will be 1 to 3 because it denotes the number of individuals and "j" denotes the number of observations within each individual.

Comment: @Mohammad You can do this easily with `ave(CD4, patient, FUN = sum)`

Comment: If I want to create probabilities from normal distribution( say mean 2 and sd 1.5) for each patient "i" and observation "j" within each "i", then what will be the code??